# How to use XQuery to extract specific XML records and output in comma delimited format?

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xpath, xquery

I'm trying to extract only `<xref>` data along with their book IDs using a XQuery (I'm new to this).

Here is the input data:

```
  <book id="6636551">
    <master_information>
        <book_xref>
            <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">72771KAM3</xref>
            <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US72771KAM36</xref>
        </book_xref>
    </master_information>
    <book_details>
        <price>24.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
    </book_details>
  </book>
  <book id="119818569">
    <master_information>
        <book_xref>
            <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">070185UL5</xref>
            <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US070185UL50</xref>
        </book_xref>
    </master_information>
    <book_details>
        <price>19.25</price>
        <publish_date>2002-11-01</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
    </book_details>
  </book>
  <book id="119818568">
  <master_information>
        <book_xref>
            <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">070185UK7</xref>
            <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US070185UK77</xref>
        </book_xref>
    </master_information>
    <book_details>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2004-05-01</publish_date>
        <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
  society in England, the young survivors lay the 
  foundation for a new society.</description>
    </book_details>
  </book>
  <book id="119818567">
    <master_information>
        <book_xref>
            <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">070185UJ0</xref>
            <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US070185UJ05</xref>
        </book_xref>
    </master_information>
    <book_details>
        <price>4.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
        <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
  conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
    </book_details>
  </book>
```

Expected output format **1**:

```
  <book id="6636551">
    <master_information>
        <book_xref>
            <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">72771KAM3</xref>
            <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US72771KAM36</xref>
        </book_xref>
    </master_information>
  </book>
```

XQuery that I'm using for format 1:

```
  for$x in //book_xref/xref
  return $x
```

Question for format 1: I tried including book id separately so that it's included in the output but it doesn't match the expected format as I mentioned above. How do I get the book id to be fetched as well in the output per the format?

Expected output format **2** (comma delimited):

```
  book_id, xref_type, xref_type_id, xref
  6636551, Fiction, 1, 72771KAM3
  6636551, Non_Fiction, 2, US72771KAM36
  119818569, Fiction, 1, 070185UL5
  119818569, Non_Fiction, 2, US070185UL50
  etc.
```

Question for format 2: How can I get output in comma delimited format through XQuery? Do I need to stick to XSLT for that?

I appreciate your response.

Comment: `//book_xref/xref` selects `xref` elements, if you want `book` elements then you need to select them e.g. `//book[.//book_xref/xref]`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks for responding. If I do that it still shows `<book_details>` node which I need to omit. I simply want `<xref>` data along with the book id irrespective of how many other nodes are present inside `<book>` but outside `<xref>`. Hope my question makes sense!

Comment: For the CSV use e.g. `//book//book_xref/xref/string-join((ancestor::book/@id, @type, @type_id, .), ',')`.

Comment: If you want to manipulate the node structure then in XQuery you need to write a function that does that i.e. takes the `book` element and removes the contents you don't want by constructing a shallow copy and then eliminating the contents you don't want. That kind of transformation would be a good job for XSLT.

Comment: @MartinHonnen for the CSV part, that worked like a charm! Thanks. I tried filtering to 'fiction' type by using:
`where $x//xref/@type='Fiction'`
but that doesn't seem to work. How can I filter?

Comment: I would simply use a predicate in a step of the path e.g. `//book//book_xref/xref[@type = 'Fiction']/string-join((ancestor::book/@id, @type, @type_id, .), ',')`

Comment: Nice! I did try doing that before but I think I had my syntax wrong. Good to know that I don't need the where clause for that. Thanks for your responses! I really appreciate it. Very helpful. If you want to post it as an answer, I can mark it as the "answer". :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the CSV you can use `string-join` i.e. for those four values you can use

```
//book//book_xref/xref/string-join((ancestor::book/@id, @type, @type_id, .), ',')
```

which would give a sequence of strings with the record data; if you want a single string with the header line and those data lines you can use another string-join:

```
string-join(('book_id,xref_type,xref_type_id,xref', //book//book_xref/xref/string-join((ancestor::book/@id, @type, @type_id, .), ',')), '&#10;')
```

For the transformation/XML extraction reconstruct the `book` elements with the `xref` descendants and add the `master_information` e.g.

```
//book[.//book_xref/xref]/<book id="{@id}">{master_information}</book>
```

Comment: The code execution for transformation/XML extraction runs out of main memory even with a RAM of 16GB. Is any kind of performance tuning possible on that query?

Comment: So which XQuery implementation do you use, how do you run the query? And which size does the input XML document have when you run out of memory with 16 GB of RAM? Are you sure you give the XQuery processor the available RAM? For instance when you run a Java program it by default does not allocate all the available memory, the are options to `java.exe` to increase/control the heap space. It might be better that you ask a new question specific to your XQuery implementation and the necessary details of XML input size.

Comment: I'm loading a 512 MB XML file into BaseX GUI on Windows 7 Pro with a RAM of 16 GB. I run the query in the query window. Not sure how to check if the BaseX gives it the available RAM. How can I check that? If this needs more details, I can create a new question for this.

Comment: I think it is better ask a BaseX specific question with those details and more, also check which Java version (32bit or 64bit) you use and check the Oracle JRE command line options to increase the Java heap space. I am not too familiar with BaseX, and certainly not with any performance/memory consumption related tuning.

Answer (score 2):

XQuery is a great way to generate CSV files from your XML data, whether the source is a single XML document or a collection of XML documents stored on the filesystem or in an XML database. There are a number of approaches one might take in XQuery. For one that uses XQuery 3.1 array structures and serialization facility to corral your data into rows and cells, see the tutorial at https://github.com/CliffordAnderson/XQuery4Humanists/blob/master/05-Generating-JSON-and-CSV.md.